# How to join table records based on the state?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, left-join, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have table that has to be joined to another table based on the state. Here is example of the table 1 data:

```
ROWID  STATE 
 34     TX
 56     NY
 67     WA
 89     TX
```

Each row in table one has state value. Table 2 has two records for each state. Here is example:

```
ROWID   STATE       NAME  
 19      TX     Chuck, Brown
 20      TX     Nick, Johnes
```

As you can see in Table 2 there are two records for Texas state. If I use `Left Outer Join` and try to do something like this:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table 2 TB2
   ON TB1.STATE = TB2.SATE
```

Then the output will be something like this:

```
34 TX Chuck, Brwon
34 TX Nick, Johnes
89 TX Chuck, Brwon
89 TX Nick, Johnes
```

Each row is duplicated, since I have two records in Table 1 for Texas. Then I have two records in Table 2 for Texas. What I would like to see is this:

```
ROWID   STATE     NAME 1         NAME 2
 34      TX    Chuck, Brwon    Nick, Johnes
```

Basically I want to merge two rows in one and then join to TABLE 1. I recently started working on this project and we use Oracle database. If anyone know good way to achieve this please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Will there always be zero, one or two `Name` records per `State`? Or is the number variable and/or unknown at design time? What determines which `Name` is `Name 1` or `Name 2`?

Comment: @APC There is always two records for the state in Table 2. Nothing special determines `Name 1` or `Name 2`. There always should be two names. All I need is to combine them (concatenate like this `Josh, Brown & Micky, Butt` for example).

Comment: What about the fact that you have two TX records in table 1 yet in your final result you only have one result record.  How should the TX record be correctly selected?  Or do you want to join the first name with the first TX record and the second name with the second TX record when ordered by ROWID?

Comment: @SentinelIf you take a closer look in my example above you will see that current code with left outer join is duplication rows. I want to merge name in one row for the same state. So for example in table 2 there should be one record for TX and name should be either like this `Chuck, Brwon & Nick, Johnes` or two columns Name 1 and Name 2. I hope this will help you understand what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: No need for outer joins unless you are wanting to return all records from table1 even when no matching records exist in table2.  See my answer below which provides the desired output, but does not use an outer join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the sample desired output I've limited the output to the first state instance in table1, and ordered the pivoted names by ID, though that happens to match the alpha order of the name field for the given example data.

See this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/52f17/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

*Note that in Oracle ROWID is a reserved name so i've changed it to ID.*

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ("ID" number, "STATE" varchar2(2))
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO Table1 ("ID", "STATE")
         VALUES (34, 'TX')
    INTO Table1 ("ID", "STATE")
         VALUES (56, 'NY')
    INTO Table1 ("ID", "STATE")
         VALUES (67, 'WA')
    INTO Table1 ("ID", "STATE")
         VALUES (89, 'TX')
SELECT * FROM dual
;

CREATE TABLE Table2
    ("ID" number, "STATE" varchar2(2), "NAME" varchar2(12))
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO Table2 ("ID", "STATE", "NAME")
         VALUES (19, 'TX', 'Chuck, Brown')
    INTO Table2 ("ID", "STATE", "NAME")
         VALUES (20, 'TX', 'Nick, Johnes')
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select t1.id
     , t2.state
     , t2.name
  from (select min(id) id, state from table1 group by state) t1
  join table2 t2
    on t1.state = t2.state
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/52f17/1/0)**:

```
| ID | STATE |         NAME |
|----|-------|--------------|
| 34 |    TX | Nick, Johnes |
| 34 |    TX | Chuck, Brown |
```

**Query 2**:

```
with t1(id, state) as (
  select min(id) id, state from table1 group by state
), t2 as (   
  select state
       , row_number() over (partition by state order by name) rn
       , name
    from table2
)
select t1.id
     , pvt.*
  from t1
  join t2 pivot (max(name) for rn in (1 name_1,2 name_2)) pvt
    on t1.state = pvt.state
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/52f17/1/1)**:

```
| ID | STATE |       NAME_1 |       NAME_2 |
|----|-------|--------------|--------------|
| 34 |    TX | Chuck, Brown | Nick, Johnes |
```

Answer (score 1):

As in one of comments under the question you said that you'd accept a single, *concatenated* NAME column, here's one option; I used CTE to create tables, so you'd need lines 13 onwards.

```
SQL> with
  2  t1 (rid, state) as
  3    (select 34, 'TX' from dual union all
  4     select 56, 'NY' from dual union all
  5     select 67, 'WA' from dual union all
  6     select 89, 'TX' from dual
  7    ),
  8  t2 (rid, state, name) as
  9    (select 19, 'TX', 'Chuck, Brown' from dual union all
 10     select 20, 'TX', 'Nick, Johnes' from dual
 11    ),
 12  -- start here
 13  it2 as
 14    (select state, listagg(name, ' & ') within group (order by null) name
 15     from t2
 16     group by state
 17    )
 18  select min(t1.rid) rid,
 19    t1.state,
 20    it2.name
 21  from t1 join it2 on t1.state = it2.state
 22  and t1.state = 'TX'
 23  group by t1.state, it2.name;

       RID ST NAME
---------- -- ------------------------------
        34 TX Chuck, Brown & Nick, Johnes

SQL>
```